# How to get mysqli_query error report properly in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, error-reporting

Really, it drive me crazy when I can't detect what error that happens. I can't handle it.

I managed to make a connection to MySQL, and check it out with:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die('Could not connect!');
if($connection){
    echo 'It's connected!';
}
```

Yeah, that say connected. Then, when I try a query, it fails without error reporting. I've tried do this to check if it fails:

```
$query = "SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['user_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if($result){
    echo 'Query OK';
}else{
    echo 'Query failed';
}
```

The browser said: Query failed. So, there's an error in my query. Then I echoed the query out with this:

```
echo $query;
// Printed in the browser: SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

Copy that value and use it in phpMyAdmin. It works. So, i guess an error occured in `mysqli_query` function. But i can't get the error message and so i don't know what's going on. I've tried this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

and this:

```
if(!$result){
     echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

Nothing happens. The browser just blank. Then, I tried to change this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

Still nothing happens. What's going on? How can I know what error occured?

I run the server in Debian with `phpinfo()`: PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3

Comment: Have you checked your `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings? Also, are you not debugging on your machine, but on a remote server? :/

Comment: @Andrea Sorry, how to check those settings? I'm editing on a remote server. Actually, I remote my server that installed in VirtualBox.

Comment: Have you seen: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)? Did you enable error logging in both your webserver and PHP? Have you checked your webservers error log and PHP's error log?

Answer (score -2):

Guys read what they have posted, they are mixing the connections up.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die('Could not connect!');
```

So this line should read:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

With `mysqli_` you need to pass the connection  to a number of things that was not required in `mysql_`

Or you can switch your original db connect to `$dbc`

```
 $dbc = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die('Could not connect!');
```

I hope this helps!